# Auto rollback Explicit transactions after X amount of time

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have SQL Server auto rollback your transactions after a certain amount of time to avoid the blocking/locking that is caused? I have been guilty of this in the past and I hear it from many others that it is a common mistake.

For example: 
I always use a block such as this When doing deletes/updates.

```
BEGIN TRAN
--SQL Code Here
ROLLBACK TRAN
COMMIT TRAN
```

This allows me to see how many rows are affected or perform a select on the data and then I can comment out the `ROLLBACK` which will automatically `COMMIT` the `TRANSACTION`.

However, there is a possibility of the of not having the `COMMIT` highlighted/selected which causes the transaction to hang. What I am looking for is a setting such as:

```
BEGIN TRAN 15 Seconds
--SQL Code Here
ROLLBACK TRAN
COMMIT TRAN
```

This will only keep the transaction open a max of 15 seconds.

If this is not possible, does anyone have a better workflow for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a job that checks for open transactions and kills them if they've been open for a period of time and are causing blocking. But you'd have to be careful with this as you could have a large, necessary transaction that takes a while that you don't want to get killed. Imagine rolling back an index rebuild that's been running for an hour on Standard Edition.

You can use [sp_WhoIsActive](http://www.whoisactive.com/) to find open transactions that are causing blocking, though it'll take a bit of work.

But I would recommend that you don't do this and instead are diligent with your transactions in Management Studio. Any window that I ever started a transaction in gets closed when I am done. And if there's still an open transaction in it, SSMS will warn me about it so that I can commit/rollback.

Comment: Thank you Tara, This makes sense and your right, I definitely wouldn't want to kill a job that I need such as a report, index, or any type of long running job. I did notice that there was a column for the program name, this can list your job name as "SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x8469FD7F1E8C2C4CB15BCA3E7CFAEB9D : Step 1)" for example.. but it is still best not to attempt this and just be more diligent. Just trying to avoid the fire :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't like leaving things to chance, so something like this means you always commit or rollback.

```
DECLARE @testing char(1) = 'Y'

BEGIN TRAN

--Do stuff

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
 IF @testing = 'Y'
 BEGIN
  -- Perform some tests/queries to check the update is correct
  -- ...then...
  ROLLBACK 
  RAISERROR(N'THE TRANSACTION WAS AUTOMATICALLY ROLLED BACK',0,0)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  COMMIT
  RAISERROR(N'THE TRANSACTION WAS AUTOMATICALLY COMMITTED',0,0)
 END
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for use in your SSMS session windows, you could do something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
--SQL Code Here

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30.000'

ROLLBACK TRAN
COMMIT TRAN
```

It's maybe not a great solution. You still have to remember to highlight it, and it may roll back a modification you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I did find that I could change my workflow a bit that seems to hold some merit and might appeal to some people better. Instead of commenting out a section of the code, you can use this base instead.

```
 BEGIN TRAN 
--SQL CODE

IF @@TRANCOUNT >0 
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRAN
PRINT 'TRANSACTION WAS AUTOMATICALLY ROLLED BACK'
END
```

The workflow would be that instead of commenting out the `ROLLBACK TRAN`, you would instead add the `COMMIT TRAN` right above the `IF` statement. Though it still doesn't fix the problem if you do not hight the code.